How do Christians of the church of Jesus of latter day saints reconcile the teaching that no man has ever seen or can see God?
I was approached yesterday by a lady with a very beautiful western accent who gave me a booklet about the church of Jesus Christ of latter day saints. In the booklet I was introduced to a prophet named Joseph Smith who claims that he saw the Father and Jesus Christ in the year 1829. Joseph Smith received the lesser priesthood(Aaronic priesthood) from them and later received the greater priesthood(Melchizedek) from the inner circle apostles. Now they are also trinitarians like me but Paul taught me that no man has ever or can see God.
1 Timothy 6:16

who alone has immortality, who dwells in unapproachable light, whom no one has ever seen or can see. To him be honor and eternal dominion. Amen.

but then Joseph Smith saw the Father and Jesus Christ in a vision, how do hey reconcile what Joseph Smith said and this verse?

Just to point out that some who claim to be 'trinitarians' are diametrically at odds with mainstream, orthodox, trinitarianism. This question may relate to that, but I simply comment that even if your idea of 'the trinity' agrees with the LDS idea of 'the trinity', that would not necessarily mean that their explanation of this query you have should be taken as gospel truth.  Have you checked out their complex doctrine of deities begetting spirits who then become deities also? That could colour their answer to this question, as any idea of a 'supreme' Father might allow them to view the one

seen along with one Smith said was Jesus Christ, to be a ‘lesser’ Father, and not the ‘supreme’ Father. They might also dismiss the matter as ‘merely’ a vision, and not an actual sighting.  Answers should be interesting.

This has been asked before for sure, let me check the questions.

I was going to ask something similar. Perhaps you should hop in the chat? Careful though, everyone get's pointy about doctrine and belief.

@Wyrsa If you ask this in chat, I might be tempted to also just point to the old question, lol.

@Anne, he doctrine of the Holy Trinity is very simple, three beings with a united divine will and who collectively form the Godhead. Nothing more, nothing less. It is not complex unless some converts made it complex. God is simple because the truth is simple and so is the doctrine of the holy trinity

@SoFewAgainstSoMany A man-made version of the deepest doctrine in the Bible will likely be 'simple'. To start a claim that the Trinity is simply "three beings..." immediately indicates a simple version that makes sense to those who only want to deal with "a simple God" - one they can explain to their own satisfaction. The God of the Bible is complex, not "simple."

@Anne, his own existence is complex because he has no beginning or end of days, that is complex but his three in one and one in three nature is simple that God in the Bible  by default refers to the Father, God collectively refers to the three because of the us phrase in the book of Genesis. He uses that term because they work as a team

As a member of The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints, I consider myself a Christian – but to avoid confusion, I would not call myself a trinitarian, because that implies adoption of the definition in the Nicene Creed and/or Athanasian Creed. We do believe in God the Father, Jesus Christ the Son, and the Holy Ghost, but it's different from the credal definition. I think most Latter-day Saints would agree with your simple definition in the comments.

@SamuelBradshaw, yes God is simple and intends it to be so. The creation is simple and so is the truth.
